# transform rows to some columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have the following data:

```
RecordYear TestA  TestB  TestC  TestD
2013        100   200    300    400
2014        150   250    350    450
```

I want to display:

```
2013 TestType  Result  2014 Test Result
     TestA     100          TestA 150
     TestB     200          TestB 250
     TestC     300          TestC 350
     TestD     400          TestD 450
```

I've used unpivot to get part way there, but my query ends up with:

```
2013
TestA  100
TestB  200
TestC  300
TestD  400

2014
TestA  150
TestB  250
TestC  350
TestD  450
```

I don't know how to move the 2014 grouping so that it is next to the 2013 group.  Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: You are probably very close. Please take a the time to provide a script that loads the sample data (or better a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6) as well as your query so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the result you want by using a CTE to do the pivot and then self-joining on test type

```
WITH pv 
     AS (SELECT recordyear, 
                col, 
                val 
         FROM   table1 p 
                UNPIVOT (val 
                        FOR col IN (testa, 
                                    testb, 
                                    testc, 
                                    testd) ) AS unpvt) 
SELECT a.col [2013 TestType], 
       a.val [ Result ], 
       b.col [2014 TestType], 
       b.val [ Result] 
FROM   pv a 
       INNER JOIN pv b 
               ON a.col = b.col 
WHERE  a.recordyear = 2013 
       AND b.recordyear = 2014
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee7dc/15)

However it does have limitations

- If the tests taken are different you may want an outer join
- Won't work well if you want more than one year
- The column names are hardcoded to match the where

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by taking the UNION and just keep a Id 1-4 for each year's result set for joining. Its simple

```
    ;WITH CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT 1 ID, RecordYear,'TESTA' TESTTYPE,TESTA Result FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2013
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 ID,RecordYear,'TESTB' TESTTYPE,TESTB Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2013
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ID,RecordYear,'TESTC' TESTTYPE,TESTC Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2013
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 ID,RecordYear,'TESTD' TESTTYPE,TESTD Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2013
    )
    ,CTE2 AS
    (
        SELECT 1 ID,RecordYear,'TESTA' TEST,TESTA Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2014
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 ID,RecordYear,'TESTB' TEST,TESTB Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2014
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ID,RecordYear,'TESTC' TEST,TESTC Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2014
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 ID,RecordYear,'TESTD' TEST,TESTD Result  FROM #TABLE WHERE RecordYear=2014
    )
    SELECT NULL '2013' ,CTE1.TESTTYPE,CTE1.Result,NULL '2014',CTE2.TEST,CTE2.Result 
    FROM CTE1
    JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.ID=CTE2.ID
```